# Single clickspan to multiple strings android (updated code)

Tags: java, android, layout, spannablestring

Hi i have a list of 10 spannable strings and i want to attach a single click span to specific words of each string but problem is how will i know which word is clicked in clickable span onClick() method?

```
 ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
  // Here i have to know which one is clicked
        }
    };

    List<SpannableString> spannableStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> startIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> endIndexes = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        spannableStrings.get(i).setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndexes.get(i), 
endIndexes.get(i), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

Comment: show what you have tried ..

Comment: I have updated my question with code

Comment: @Mohit please have a look at my code

Comment: are you passing list data to adapter ??